# org.json.JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject facebook login

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to login through Facebook in Android app but am getting this error while running emulator. getting profile information but keep on loading after login

Here is while running app on android studio emulator

> ```
> D/tictic_: https://test.mik.digital/API/index.php?p=signup
> D/tictic_index.php?p=signup: {"fb_id":"23944184518020","first_name":"manu","last_name":"sinha","profile_pic":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/2394418897518020\/picture?width=500&width=500","gender":"m","version":"1.7","signup_type":"facebook","device":"android"}
> D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9210d840: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9211b550)
>
> at com.mik.Accounts.Login_A.Parse_signup_data(Login_A.java:432)
> at com.mik.Accounts.Login_A$7.Responce(Login_A.java:419)
> at com.mik.SimpleClasses.ApiRequest$2.onErrorResponse(ApiRequest.java:61)
>
> LOGIN_A.JAVA line no 432
> ```

Login function java file

```
public void Parse_signup_data(String loginData){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(loginData);
            String code=jsonObject.optString("code");
            if(code.equals("200")){
                JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("msg");
                JSONObject userdata = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(Variables.u_id,userdata.optString("fb_id"));
                editor.putString(Variables.f_name,userdata.optString("first_name"));
                editor.putString(Variables.l_name,userdata.optString("last_name"));
                editor.putString(Variables.u_name,userdata.optString("username"));
                editor.putString(Variables.gender,userdata.optString("gender"));
                editor.putString(Variables.u_pic,userdata.optString("profile_pic"));
                editor.putString(Variables.api_token,userdata.optString("tokon"));
                editor.putBoolean(Variables.islogin,true);
                editor.commit();
                Variables.sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(Variables.pref_name,MODE_PRIVATE);
                Variables.user_id=Variables.sharedPreferences.getString(Variables.u_id,"");

                Variables.Reload_my_videos=true;
                Variables.Reload_my_notification=true;
                top_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class));



            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, ""+jsonObject.optString("msg"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

here is the php code api call from App

```
function signup()
    {
        require_once("config.php");
        $input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
        $event_json = json_decode($input,true);
        //print_r($event_json);
        
        //get headers
        $headers = apache_request_headers();
        
        $header_device = $headers['Device'];
        $header_version = $headers['Version'];
        $header_tokon = $headers['Tokon'];
        $header_deviceid = $headers['Deviceid'];
        //get headers
        
        if(isset($event_json['fb_id']) && isset($event_json['first_name']) && isset($event_json['last_name']))
        {
            $fb_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($event_json['fb_id'] , ENT_QUOTES));
            $first_name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($event_json['first_name'] , ENT_QUOTES));
            $last_name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($event_json['last_name'] , ENT_QUOTES));
            $gender=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($event_json['gender'] , ENT_QUOTES));
            $profile_pic=htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($event_json['profile_pic']));
            $version=htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($event_json['version']));
            $device=htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($event_json['device']));
            $signup_type=htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($event_json['signup_type']));
            $username=$first_name.rand();
            
            $log_in="select * from users where fb_id='".$fb_id."' ";
            $log_in_rs=mysqli_query($conn,$log_in);
            
            $get_device_tkon="select * from device_tokon where fb_id='".$fb_id."' and phone_id='".$header_deviceid."' ";
            $get_device_tkon1=mysqli_query($conn,$get_device_tkon);
            $dvice_tokon=mysqli_fetch_object($get_device_tkon1);
            
            if(mysqli_num_rows($log_in_rs))
            {   
                $rd=mysqli_fetch_object($log_in_rs);  
                 
                if($rd->block=='0')
                {
                    $array_out = array();
                     $array_out[] = 
                        //array("code" => "200");
                        array(
                            "fb_id" => $rd->fb_id,
                            "action" => "login",
                            "profile_pic" => $rd->profile_pic,
                            "first_name" => $rd->first_name,
                            "last_name" => $rd->last_name,
                            "username" => "@".$rd->username,
                            "verified" => $rd->verified,
                            "bio" => $rd->bio,
                            "gender" => $rd->gender,
                            "tokon" => $dvice_tokon->tokon
                        );
                    
                    $output=array( "code" => "200", "msg" => $array_out);
                    print_r(json_encode($output, true));
                }
                else
                {
                    $array_out = "error in login";
                    $output=array( "code" => "201", "msg" => $array_out);
                    print_r(json_encode($output, true));
                }
                
            }   
            else
            {
                
                $qrry_1="insert into users(fb_id,username,first_name,last_name,profile_pic,version,device,signup_type,gender)values(";
                $qrry_1.="'".$fb_id."',";
                $qrry_1.="'".$username."',";
                $qrry_1.="'".$first_name."',";
                $qrry_1.="'".$last_name."',";
                $qrry_1.="'".$profile_pic."',";
                $qrry_1.="'".$version."',";
                $qrry_1.="'".$device."',";
                $qrry_1.="'".$signup_type."',";
                $qrry_1.="'".$gender."'";
                $qrry_1.=")";
                if(mysqli_query($conn,$qrry_1))
                {
                     $last_insert_fb_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                     
                    //register tokon
                    $tokon=time().rand();
                    $qrry_1="insert into device_tokon(fb_id,tokon,phone_id)values(";
                    $qrry_1.="'".$fb_id."',";
                    $qrry_1.="'".$tokon."',";
                    $qrry_1.="'".$header_deviceid."'";
                    $qrry_1.=")";
                    mysqli_query($conn,$qrry_1);
                    //register tokon
                    
                     $array_out = array();
                     $array_out[] = 
                        //array("code" => "200");
                        array(
                            "fb_id" => $fb_id,
                            "username" => "@".$username,
                            "action" => "signup",
                            "profile_pic" => $profile_pic,
                            "first_name" => $first_name,
                            "last_name" => $last_name,
                            "signup_type" => $signup_type,
                            "gender" => $gender,
                            "tokon" => $tokon
                        );
                    
                    $output=array( "code" => "200", "msg" => $array_out);
                    print_r(json_encode($output, true));
                }
```

Comment: Which is line 432?

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(loginData);